# iPad keyboard with swipe-typing, number row, dot and comma?

Tags: ipad, keyboard, key

Greetings StackOverflowers!

I am in desperate search for a decent keyboard for iPad. I hadn't found one; I've tried multiple: Gboard; Fleksy; GO Keyboard; SwiftKey.

My request is pretty easy:

1. Keyboard should support swipes (like swiftkey and gboard).
2. Number row to be always on top. 1234567890 -> and the numbers should have symbols on the long press.
3. Comma and dot should be ALWAYS ON keys that are available from the keyboard without any additional key presses. I need this for at least Russian, English and Norwegian to be so!
4. Keyboard has to have Enter and Backspace keys and allow for fast language switching.
5. Ideally, if keyboard would allow size change and one-hand typing.

That's basically it. Oh and black/dark/night theme, but probably all of keyboard does have this already.

Do you know such a keyboard?

Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OT

Comment: Why do you consider this as offtopic? @Berto99